# ValidationAttribute Redux

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, validation, lambda

Ref to:[Creating a ValidationAttribute to ensure unique column values.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859495/validationattribute-to-ensure-property-value-is-unique)

Ok... Let's try reframing the question:

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637672/linq-2-sql-generic-where-clause) I have ripped this code:

```
    static TEntity Get<TEntity, TKey>(this DataContext ctx, TKey key) where TEntity : class
    {
        var table = ctx.GetTable<TEntity>();
        var pkProp = (from member in ctx.Mapping.GetMetaType(typeof(TEntity)).DataMembers
                      where member.IsPrimaryKey
                      select member.Member).Single();
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
        MemberExpression memberExp;
        switch (pkProp.MemberType)
        {
            case MemberTypes.Field: memberExp = Expression.Field(param, (FieldInfo)pkProp); break;
            case MemberTypes.Property: memberExp = Expression.Property(param, (PropertyInfo)pkProp); break;
            default: throw new NotSupportedException("Invalid primary key member: " + pkProp.Name);
        }
        Expression body = Expression.Equal(
        memberExp, Expression.Constant(key, typeof(TKey)));
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, param);
        return table.Single(predicate);
    }
```

It's a DataContext Extension Method that has stuff I need. However, it requires generic parms I don't have available - attributes don't allow generic subcalsses, so....

I have hacked the code to this point:

```
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
        SomeDataContext context = SomeDataContext.GetNewDataContext();
        var table = context.GetTable(_EntityType);
        var codeProp = (from member in context.Mapping.GetMetaType(_EntityType).DataMembers
                        where member.Name == _PropertyName
                        select member.Member).Single();
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(_EntityType, "x");
        MemberExpression memberExp = Expression.Property(param, (PropertyInfo)codeProp); 
        Expression body = Expression.Equal(memberExp, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(char)));
        Type lambdaType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(_EntityType, typeof(bool)); 
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda(lambdaType, body, param); 
        object code = table.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        if (code != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This line is bad:

```
        object code = table.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
```

as I stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858987/trying-to-get-generic-when-generic-is-not-available) the answers to which don't help.

- `var enumerator =
  ((IEnumerable)table).GetEnumerator();object
  code = enumerator.MoveNext() ?
  enumerator.Value : null;`
  is not useful in my attempt to build the expression tree.
- `IEnumerable<object> tableGeneric = 
  ((IEnumerable)table).OfType<object>();`
  has issues when I try:
  `object code = tableGeneric.FirstOrDefault(predicate);`

So, I am pretty stuck. Any ideas out there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end-run you may be looking for is that as far as I can tell you really want a method like:

```
public bool IsValid<TEntity>()
{
    // validation logic goes here
}
```

So that you can perform the check(s) that you need, but you need to implement it in a method that only has the run-time-type available to it:

```
public bool IsValid(Type entityType)
{
    // ???
}
```

If that is the case, then you implement the first code-block with the logic you need, and you implement the second method as:

```
public bool IsValidWrapper(Type entityType)
{
    // You may want to be stricter than this, but the essence is to
    // get a handle to the generic method first...
    MethodInfo genMethod = GetType().GetMethod("IsValid");

    // Bind it to the type you want to operate on...
    MethodInfo method = genMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);

    // And invoke it...
    return (bool) method.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

It won't win any beauty contests or performance crowns, but it will get you what you need. And note that if performance is a concern, you could keep a lookup from `Type` to a delegate with the signature `bool delegate()` so that you do not have to use slow reflection for a given type more than once to perform the type binding.